# signInAnonymously:FAILURE Google FireBase

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I am facing this issue while using **Firebase storage**.

> com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occured. [ OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED]

I am using sample code for Firebase Storage. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to

> FireBase Console

and enable Anonymous sign-in as shown in picture below.
[image]

Hope this can help you.